# CarrierWave upload picture and show in html page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have finished to use Carrierwave to upload the picture. 
And the picture has been store in default file.

```
uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}
```

Now I want the picture to be shown in my html homepage.

How could I pull the picture from this default file route.

My html code is

```
<img class="img-rounded" src="uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}" alt="Generic placeholder image" width="200" height="160">
```

However, in this way, the picture can not be shown.
Thanks for helping

Comment: I fix this, Thanks

Comment: Well then delete this question or post the answer but I am guessing you should just delete the question.

Comment: The answer is <%= image_tag a.avatar_url(:normal) %> normal is the picture size I define in avatar uploader. Thanks guys